# How do I get an Applications folder in the Dock in OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, dock

I created a new user on my OS X Yosemite. This user, for some reason, doesn't have an Applications folder in the Dock, where all the applications show in nice large icons. I tried all kind of things, such as dragging the Applications directory to the toolbar (from Finder) but that didn't help either.

Any ideas why I don't have that folder/button on this new user's Dock?

Comment: Do you mean in the Dock? Could you add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: Related: [Restore Applications folder to dock](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175712/restore-applications-folder-to-dock) on Ask Different.